# Karma Jasmine - use service method from component

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have the following code in my component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.formattedPacks = this.protocolPackService.formatPacks(this.selectedPacks);
}
```

In my test, I get the following error:

```
this.protocolPackService.formatPacks is not a function
```

The `formatPacks` method is a helper function without any server request that returns an array. I don't want it to behave like any other service method that I have to spy and mock with a result.

I can mock `formatPacks` too, but I use it in two different tests and it should produce different output for each.

How I can make sure it is executed properly in my test?

I mock other `protocolPackService` methods (API calls) in my test as follows:

```
const ppackService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ProtocolPackService', ['listPacks', 'findPackDevices']);

    const packListResult = '{}';
    const packDevicesResult = '{}';

    const getPackListSpy = ppackService.listPacks.and.returnValue( Promise.resolve(packListResult) );
    const findPackDevicesSpy = ppackService.findPackDevices.and.returnValue( of(packDevicesResult) );
```

in my providers:

```
providers: [
            { provide: ProtocolPackService, useValue: ppackService },
            ToastService]
```

Comment: Did you mock `protocolPackService` in the tests or are using `useValue` for providing the type requested for the variable `protocolPackService` ?

Comment: @Ankesh added the code i'm using, I did mock it in the tests and also using `useValue`

Comment: @TheUnreal Did my answer worked ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the mentioned details, if you need to use the original method for `formatPacks`, you need to create a separate instance for that dependency and then use it in your test.

Try this for your tests

```
beforeEach(
  "...",
  inject([ProtocolPackService], protoPackService => {
    ppackService = jasmine.createSpyObj("ProtocolPackService", {
      listPacks: () => {},
      findPackDevices: () => {},
      formatPacks: packs => {
        protoPackService.formatPacks(packs);
      },
    });
  }),
);
```

Comment: Not sure if this code make any change, if I remove the 'formatPacks' from the my `createSpyObj` methods and place your code, I get `this.protocolPackService.formatPacks is not a function`. One of the component methods call this service method, not the test.

Comment: Let me get a hold of a computer to look into this error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a stub for `ProtocolPackService` which is `ppackService`, test is expecting formatPacks to be present in `ppackService`. That is you have explicitly create it.
If you provide the service in the module, it will be used in all the components imported in that module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem with your approach is that you need to use `useClass`, and create a stub:

```
class PpackServiceStub{
    formatPacks(){
      // return whatever you are expecting, be it promise or Observable using of()
    }
    // create other methods similary with expected Output
  }
```

and in `providers`

```
providers: [
  { provide: ProtocolPackService, useClass: PpackServiceStub },
    ToastService
   ]
```

Now, Lets suppose you want to check 2 different behaviors of service , then you need to create a `spy`. I'll take an example of a function `checkIfHuman()` , so I'll add:

```
class PpackServiceStub{
    formatPacks(){
      // return whatever you are expecting, be it promise or Observable using of()
    }
    checkIfHuman(){
      return of({val : true})
    }
  }
```

with `component.ts` code as something like:

```
ngOnInit() {    
  this.protocolPackService.checkIfHuman().subscribe(res =>  
   { 
    this.humanFlag =  res.val
   })
}
```

make `protocolPackService` as `public` in `component` constructor,  so that we can spy in `spec` file as below:

```
  it('On ngOnInit should assign value as TRUE', () => {
    spyOn(component.protocolPackService, 'checkIfHuman').and.returnValue(of({val: true}));
    // you dont even need to create this spy because you already have the same value being returned in "PpackServiceStub" 
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.humanFlag).toBeTruthy();    
  });

  it('On ngOnInit should assign value as FALSE', () => {
    spyOn(component.protocolPackService, 'checkIfHuman').and.returnValue(of({val: false}));
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.humanFlag).toBeFalsy();    
  });
```